# multiline insert (Shift-I) no longer works in vim

Tags: vim

I used to be able to use ctrl-v and Shift-I to do multi line insert.  I think it MIGHT have been caused by installing gvim?  I have spent hours trying to fix this.  I have tried running without plugins and removing .vimrc

my .vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set nocompatible
set tabstop=2     "Set size of tab to 2 spaces
set shiftwidth=2 
set expandtab     "Turns tab into spaces
set autoindent    "Automatically indents to the same indent next line
set smarttab      "return on a tabbed line returns to that tabbed position
set number        
set showcmd       "shows last command typed
set wildmenu      "Autocomplete menu that pops up at bottom
set showmatch
""SEARCH""
set incsearch     "search as characters are entered
set hlsearch      "highlights all words
""PASTE MODE""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
nnoremap <F2> :set invpaste paste?<CR> 
set pastetoggle=<F2>                   
set showmode                           
""SET COLORS"""""
colo solarized
set background=dark

augroup filetypedetect
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.hbs setfiletype html
    " associate *.hbs with html filetype
augroup END
```

Global vimrc

```
runtime! debian.vim 

if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

Comment: What happens when you try to do insert on visual block mode? Does visual block mode work otherwise, for other operations? If you type `:vmap I` to check for mappings of `I` in visual mode, do you see any mappings listed?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: If I try Shift-I in visual block it works as if I am just inserting. I tried `:vmap I` and it says no "No mapping found".

Comment: When you are done the insert how are you exiting visual block mode after making the edit.  If you're using anything other than `<Esc>` (`<Ctrl-c>`, custom mapping, etc.), try using `<Esc>`.  Edits don't get copied to every line of the selection until you leave visual block mode, and depending on how you leave you can unintentionally prevent the edits from happening.

Comment: So I used to <ctrl-v>, make my vertical selection, <Shift-i> Type, usually I see the text update as I type it. Then hit <ESC>.  But now your right, I can type the changes and hit <ESC> it will apply those changes.  The only problem is that in certain situations the way it used to work out was so much better.

Comment: I have never known vim to show the changes on all lines while you were making the change.  There may be a plugin or a newer version of vim that does this but traditionally it never did on its own afaik.

Comment: Thank you Randy I think you are right.  I am not sure what I am getting mixed up.